# How can I exclude files from indexing but include them in .war file?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

We build with IDEA a Maven-managed web application for which we generate bundles with Webpack fairly often in `main/webapp/resources`. Ideally these files shouldn’t be indexed, but if I exclude them in *Project Structure* or in the Project tree, they aren’t included in the .war file when we run Tomcat (within IDEA). Is there a way to exclude files from indexing and still include them in the web app?

Thanks.

Comment: You can change Maven build to generate the files directly in the artifact output location.

Comment: The best is never generate in the are `src/` better generate files in target directory instead.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thanks for the tip. In my reply I added your suggestion and one that, I think, works better because it improves noticeably start-up times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crux of the matter is that the (exploded) `.war` file that IDEA generates when running Tomcat within the IDE follows different rules than the one you get executing `mvn package`. Whatever you exclude in IDEA is also removed from the webapp.

There are two ways to solve the issue.

## 1. Build using Maven

The first one is to have Maven build your module instead of IDEA. To do that you need to change the *Before launch* command: remove the default, click on +, choose *Run Maven Goal* and type in *Command line* something like `-DskipTests -pl {module_name} package` (see image below).
[image]
The profile will be picked up from whatever you have selected in IDEA (that was unexpectedly clever from the guys at IntelliJ, so kudos to them) but it has the drawback that it makes a full build each time you start Tomcat. In our case that’s roughly 25 seconds, which is quite a lot.

## 2. Edit the artifact

The second way, which is faster because it takes advantage of the automatic compilation of classes that IDEA makes in the background, is to edit the war artifact. To do so go to *Build* → *Build Artifacts...* → *:war exploded* → *Edit...*, select the tab *Output Layout* and create a directory of the same name (`resources` in my case) and add a *Directory Content* entry. Check the following image for details.
[image]
You will also need to change the *Before launch* similarly to the first solution, but just select the affected artifact.

---

**UPDATE**

Because the default war and exploded wars are imported from Maven, any change to e.g. the selected profile accompanied by a `clean` command reverts the artifact to the default layout, so if you use this solution you’d better create a duplicate war artifact.